# Acumatica Rest API Returning Errors Differently In Code than Postman

Tags: acumatica

This problem has been driving me nuts for hours and I can't figure out what's going on. For example's sake, I have created a test action on a custom page in my Acumatica installation.

This test action is as follows:

```
public PXAction<UsrPCMJob> testAction;
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Test")]
[PXButton()]
public virtual void TestAction()
{
   throw new PXException("This is just a test action!");
}
```

I have created a rest endpoint for this page and mapped the test action.

If I create the post in Postman, it works as expected:

```
{"entity":{"Job":{"value":"0228467"}},"parameters":null}
```

and I get the following as a response:

```
"exceptionMessage": "PX.Data.PXException: This is just a test action!
```

However, in code (PHP, using Guzzle for my request), even though my json body is the same:

```
{"entity":{"Job":{"value":"0228467"}},"parameters":null}
```

I get this error message:

```
{"message":"An error has occurred.","exceptionMessage":"PX.Data.PXException: Error #251: Failed to commit the Job row.\r\n at PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.SyStep.a(Object A_0, PXFilterRow[] A_1, PXFilterRow[] A_2)\r\n at PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.ExportTableHelper.ExportTable()","exceptionType":"PX.Api.ContractBased.OutcomeEntityHasErrorsException","stackTrace":" at System.Monads.ArgumentCheck.CheckNull[TSource](TSource source, Func`1 exceptionSource)\r\n at PX.Api.ContractBased.EntityService.GetOperationResult(EntityImpl entity, EntityExportContextBuilder entityExportContextBuilder, PXSYTable exportedKeys, List`1 errors) in F:\\Bld2\\AC-FULL60U3-JOB1\\sources\\NetTools\\PX.Api.ContractBased\\EntityService.cs:line 457\r\n at PX.Api.ContractBased.EntityService.Invoke(ISystemContract systemContract, String version, String name, EntityImpl entity, ActionImpl action, CbOperationContext operationContext) in F:\\Bld2\\AC-FULL60U3-JOB1\\sources\\NetTools\\PX.Api.ContractBased\\EntityService.cs:line 720\r\n at PX.Api.ContractBased.Soap.EntityGateBase.InvokeImpl(EntityImpl entity, ActionImpl action) in F:\\Bld2\\AC-FULL60U3-JOB1\\sources\\NetTools\\PX.Api.ContractBased\\Soap\\EntityGateBase.cs:line 144\r\n at PX.Api.ContractBased.Soap.EntityGateV2.PX.Api.ContractBased.IRestGate.Invoke(EntityImpl entity, ActionImpl action) in F:\\Bld2\\AC-FULL60U3-JOB1\\sources\\NetTools\\PX.Api.ContractBased\\Soap\\EntityGateV2.cs:line 357\r\n at PX.Api.ContractBased.Soap.WebApiSoapController.RestInvoke(EntityEndpoint endpoint, String objectName, String actionName, ActionInvocation invocation) in F:\\Bld2\\AC-FULL60U3-JOB1\\sources\\NetTools\\PX.Api.ContractBased\\Soap\\WebApiSoapController.cs:line 414\r\n at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"}
```

My php guzzle client that I created works fine on other requests that use actions, but not for this test action or a few other actions.

Any help you can offer would be GREATLY appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can also present your page and DAC classes in order to easier to get help?